# TypeError: Cannot read property 'sort' of undefined

Tags: typescript, vue.js, jestjs

I'm trying to run a test and I'm returning  `TypeError: Cannot read property 'sort' of undefined`

Any ideas?

Thanks

test:

```
import { cloneDeep } from "lodash";
import Vue from "vue";
import Vuex from "vuex";

import mockStoreModule from "@app/tests/support/mockStoreModule";
import analytics from "@store/modules/analytics";
import { mount } from "@vue/test-utils";

import TopConditionSetPresenter from "@app/components/analytics-new/top-conditions/top-condition-set-presenter.vue";

describe("TopConditionSetPresenter component", () => {
    const campaignsMockStore = mockStoreModule({});
    Vue.use(Vuex);
    const store = new Vuex.Store({
        modules: {
            campaigns: campaignsMockStore,
            analytics: cloneDeep(analytics),
        },
    });
    describe("component rendering", () => {
        it("should mount component without error", () => {
            mount(TopConditionSetPresenter, { store });
        });
    });
});
```

Structure

```
export interface ImpressionDataTopConditions {
    name: string;
    icon: string;
    conditions: TopConditionsData[];
}

export interface TopConditionsData {
    name: string;
    values: TopConditionValues;
}

export interface TopConditionValues {
    value: string;
    altValue: { [key: string]: number };
    total: number;
    totalDeliveryPercentage: number;
}
```

Jest test response:

```
 FAIL  
  TopConditionSetPresenter component
    component rendering
      ✕ should mount component without error (16ms)

  ● TopConditionSetPresenter component › component rendering › should mount component without error

    TypeError: Cannot read property 'sort' of undefined

      42 | 
      43 |         get sortedConditions(): TopConditionsData[] {
    > 44 |             return this.conditionSet.conditions.sort(
         | ^
      45 |                 (a, b) =>
      46 |                     (b.values.altValue[this.selectedTopCondition] || b.values.totalDeliveryPercentage) -
      47 |                     (a.values.altValue[this.selectedTopCondition] || a.values.totalDeliveryPercentage)
```

Component

```
<template>
    <div class="top-condition-set" data-testid="top-condition-set">
        <p>
            <i class="mr-2 fa" :class="conditionSet.icon" />
            <strong>{{ conditionSet.name }}</strong>
        </p>

        <v-progress-linear
            v-for="(cond, i) in sortedConditions"
            :key="i"
            class="top-condition"
            :color="selectedTopCondition === cond.values.value ? 'pink' : 'blue'"
            height="30"
            :value="cond.values.altValue[selectedTopCondition] || cond.values.totalDeliveryPercentage"
            @click="barClicked(cond.values.value)"
        >
            <span class="condition-stat">
                {{ cond.name }} :
                {{ cond.values.altValue[selectedTopCondition] || cond.values.totalDeliveryPercentage }} %
            </span>
        </v-progress-linear>
    </div>
</template>
<script lang="ts">
    import Vue from "vue";
    import Component from "vue-class-component";
    import { Prop } from "vue-property-decorator";

    import { ImpressionDataTopConditions, TopConditionsData } from "@store/modules/analytics";

    @Component({})
    export default class TopConditionSetPresenter extends Vue {
        @Prop() selectedTopCondition: string;

        @Prop({
            default: () => {
                return {};
            },
            type: Object,
        })
        conditionSet: ImpressionDataTopConditions;

        get sortedConditions(): TopConditionsData[] {
            return this.conditionSet.conditions.sort(
                (a, b) =>
                    (b.values.altValue[this.selectedTopCondition] || b.values.totalDeliveryPercentage) -
                    (a.values.altValue[this.selectedTopCondition] || a.values.totalDeliveryPercentage)
            );
        }

        barClicked(selectedCondition: string): void {
            this.$emit("selected", selectedCondition);
        }
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Please, provide the structure of conditionSet and the test code. Without this os hard to guess what is wrong

Comment: Hi @FelipeBonfante I have now added further info, thanks for taking a look

Comment: You're welcome! Take a look at my responde, please!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you are not mounting the component with the props on the test and the conditionSet is undefined. You need to change the mount method on test to provide the conditionSet:

```
mount(TopConditionSetPresenter, { propsData: {
    conditionSet: theConditionSetYouWantToTest,
    selectedTopCondition: the other property from your component
}, store })
```

Take a look at the oficial docs here https://vue-test-utils.vuejs.org/api/mount.html

Comment: Thank you, appreciate the help

Answer (score 0):

define your condition first like this

```
let conditions = this.conditionSet.conditions;
return conditions.sort(
a, b) =>
```

Comment: Hi frendy unfortunately that didn't work for me

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't you pass a propData in the options when mounting your component?
It is using the default value of conditionSet which is {}, so the array conditions is undefined.

Comment: Cheers Jonathan, appreciate it